# Converting an @Entity to a projection interface manually

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I've been using Spring Data Repositories most of the time. But I've reached a use-case where I cannot use my Spring Repository to retrieve the entity that I need to return to the client.
So I have my class `ResourceEntity` which is a Spring Data Entity. And I'd like to return this entity as a `ResourceProjection`interface.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class ResourceEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String anotherFieldThatIsNotInTheProjection;
}

public interface ResourceProjection {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Usually with a Spring Repository, I'd define something like that :

```
public interface ResourceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ResourceEntity, Long> {
    Optional<ResourceProjection> getById(Long id);
}
```

In this case I can't use the "automatic proxy" generated by Spring Data to automatically implement my projection with the entity's data.

So my question is : Is there a way to "manually" convert the entity to the projection ?

Another solution I thought of is returning the entity and using Jackson annotations like @JsonIgnore to prevent some of my data to be returned, but that is not optimal with the way my code was written.

Otherwise I can always create a DTO class that will fill up with the data from the Entity. But as I have already created my projection for other purposes, I would like avoid creating a second "DTO".

Comment: Why is it you cannot use the projection like you normally would?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate Search which doesn't support projections the way Spring Repositories do. It proposes a way to make projections but I don't really like it. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections

Comment: Please make the Hibernate Search part clear in your question and tags. If that is the adviced solution then you might want to follow it (even though you might not like it yourself).

Comment: I didn't mention the Hibernate Search part because I wanted to know if there is a more general way to do this conversion, a way that I could use outside of Hibernate Search as well. Maybe I should have specified that. Is that alright, or should I change my question anyway?

Comment: Hibernate Search is quite specific and there is nothing Spring Data JPA will do to help. So you will end up with a specific solution anyway.

Comment: From the docs of Spring Data JPA "The query execution engine creates proxy instances of that interface at runtime for each element returned and forwards calls to the exposed methods to the target object.". I guessed maybe there is a Spring Data JPA class that allows me to use this query execution engine manually to do the conversion at runtime. If you say it is not possible, than the answer to my question is no and the post can be closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the projection programmatically in this way:

```
import org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.projection.SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory;

 //... 
  resourceEntity = //find resource
  ProjectionFactory pf = new SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory();
  ResourceProjection rp = pf.createProjection(ResourceProjection.class, resourceEntity)
```

Comment: Sweet, that worked like a charm. I wonder why I was not able to find this while searching on Google, thank you very much!

Comment: Just to let people know, I've encountered a limitation with `SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory`. I cannot use the `@value` annotation in my projection to call a repository because the Bean is not found. The bean reference `@myRepository` only works if the projection is directly returned by Spring data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(ResourceEntity.class)
interface ResourceProjection {
  @IdMapping
  Long getId();
  String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ResourceProjection dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ResourceProjection.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For now I got it working with `SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory` as suggested by @lucsbelt. However, if I need more advanced features for my projections, I will definitely take a look at your library. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

### Implementing interface projection using native sql query

**1. Our`ResourceEntity.java` class**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class ResourceEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**2. Creating projection Interface name `ProjectedResource.java`, which maps data collected by the SQL query from repository layer method**

```java
public interface ProjectedResource {
  Long getId();
  String getName();
  String getAnotherProperty();
}
```

**3. Creating Repository layer method: `getProjectedResources()`**

- We are considering the database table name is `resource`.
- We are only fetching `id` and `name` here.But using interface projection we can change the properties name according to our desire.

```java
@Query(name="select id, name, anotherProperty from resource", nativeQuery=true)
List<ProjectedResource> getProjectedResources();
```

Hope the issue will be resolved!